# Talend - Transposing Input File with Dynamic Number of Columns

Tags: csv, talend, unpivot, dynamic-columns, data-mapping

I have a very tricky situation and have yet to come up with my own solution using Talend. I have an input csv file that has a dynamic number of columns and need to transpose this file to create a desired output file. The input file looks like this:

```
ID1 | Units1 | Count | Val1a | Val2a | Val3a | Val1b | Val2b | Val3b | Val1c | Val2c | Val3c
ID2 | Units2 | Count | Val1d | Val2d | Val3d | Val1e | Val2e | Val3e
```

As you can see, the Val's are in triplets on each row and I need the triplets to stay together. The Count column holds a number of how many triplets are found on that row as each row is dynamic. The final output I need is:

```
ID1 | Units1 | Val1a | Val2a | Val3a
ID1 | Units1 | Val1b | Val2b | Val3b
ID1 | Units1 | Val1c | Val2c | Val3c
ID2 | Units2 | Val1d | Val2d | Val3d 
ID2 | Units2 | Val1e | Val2e | Val3e
```

I have tried pivoting and unpivoting the rows but this does not allow me to keep the triplets together. Is it possible for me to send the input file through a Java script where I parse the file and output to a csv file in this format?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to use a tJavaFlex component that allows you to create one or multiple line output per input line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to write a custom bit of Java code in a tJavaRow that should parse out the values as you need them.

You'll probably want to read the original source in as a raw input using tFileInputRaw so you can then parse the entire thing in your tJavaRow component. You'll want to add an output schema to the tJavaRow that has columns for your id, unit, value1, value2 and value3.

Because you've got lines that need to be broken down into multiple lines you are probably best off concatenating the values such as 1a, 1b, 1c and 1d together which you can then further break into separate lines using the tNormalize component which will break the row down as needed.

Off the top of my head the code in your tJavaRow component could look something like:

```
// First we split the data on the delimiter of the file, assuming comma separated for now
String[] splitData = inputrow.content.split(",");
// Initialise the three value strings
String value1 = ""
String value2 = ""
String value3 = ""
for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        // id field is the first field
        String id = splitData[i];
    } else if (i == 2) {
        unit field is the second field
        String unit = splitData[i];
    } else if (i == 3) {
        // Don't need to do anything with the count data
    } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
        // value1 fields are 4, 7, 10 etc so modulo 3 == 1
        if (value1.length == 0) {
            value1 + splitData[i];
        } else {
            // if the value field isn't empty (ie. for val1b) then we need to add a delimiter for further processing
            value1 + "|" + splitData[i];
        }
    } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
        if (value2.length == 0) {
            value2 + splitData[i];
        } else {
            value2 + "|" + splitData[i];
        }
    } else if (i % 3 == 3) {
        if (value3.length == 0) {
            value3 + splitData[i];
        } else {
            value3 + "|" + splitData[i];
        }
    }
}

// Finally we then assign these strings to their output schema columns
output_row.id = id;
output_row.unit = unit;
output_row.value1 = value1;
output_row.value2 = value2;
output_row.value3 = value3;
```

You'll have some issues with this if the contents of any of your fields can contain commas (or whatever delimiter your file has, as you will need to make a more complicated parsing method that allows for quoted field data.

From here you just need to connect the tNormalize component and have it split on the | character (or whatever you chose to instead, it should be a character that will not be found in your source data). You might need to do this three times to get your desired output (as you have three columns to normalise on).

Comment: with tJavaFlex you don't need the tNormalize :)

Comment: True but you're effectively doing what the tNormalize would do in your own hand written Java code. Not being a Java developer I'd rather use as much of the components as possible and only resort to writing Java where the components won't help me (such as this customer parser).

Comment: @BalazsGunics I was able to get this to work. I am curious though, how can I use tJavaFlex in place of tNormalize?

Comment: The [tJavaFlex component guide](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/5.4+tJavaFlex) should be of use to helping you there. I haven't used it all that much but you basically want to wrap the code you'd execute in a tJavaRow inside a for loop that loops through all of the lines of data. Depending on how comfortable you are with writing (and maintaining) Java code then that would probably be a better option.

Comment: You use a tFullRowinput -> tFlowToIterate -> tJavaFlex -> someoutput (in append mode!!) Define a schema in tJavaFlex, lets call your outputrow "parsedOut", then you can do something like: begin part: String[] dataArray = ((String)globalMap.get("input")).split("|"); for(int i = 3; i<dataArray.size ;) {   main part: parsedOut.col1 = dataArray[0]; parsedOut.col2 = dataArray[1]; parsedOut.col3 = dataArray[i]; parsedOut.col4 = dataArray[++i]; parsedOut.col5 = dataArray[++i];     end part:  }

Comment: @Balzacs Gunics maybe post it as an answer? It might be the better option. I hadn't really thought of it until you commented and was tempted to edit my answer to include the tJavaFlex code but didn't want to steal your idea. If you can provide code that works for the OPs example then I'll upvote it because it will be the better answer.

Comment: I ended up creating both solutions. @BalazsGunics solution with the tJavaFlex is much more efficient and faster than using the tJavaRow + tNormalize. Thanks for both of these solutions.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR You can add it into your answer if you want. McLovin I'm happy that my idea works as well ;)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR sorry, would u mind to help? I am in a similar situation, the columns are dynamic and I have to reduce the empty result. my column looks like this : ||453|-990|||4 with random position of pipeline |